# A plugin to align comments

Tags: comments, alignment

I often edit code where I have a general comment for a block of code and specific comment for each line. For instance, this a sample of my `.vimrc`.

```
"indentation
set autoindent                 "automatically indent
set shiftwidth=2               "auto-ident two blanks
set tabstop=2                  "tabs are two blanks
set expandtab                  "tabs are spaces
set backspace=indent,eol,start "backspaces delete auto-inserted indents

":cmdline
set showcmd        "show incomplete cmds
set wildmenu       "cmdline completion
set history=1000   "store 1000 cmd from cmdline
set laststatus=2   "always show the current file status
set noruler        "off by default, but had to reset it
set shell=/bin/zsh "use zsh
```

For now, I am able to render that kind of formatting by using [easy align](https://github.com/junegunn/vim-easy-align). However this is quite limited because it natively only considers few delimiters. For vim (whose comments start by `"`) and LaTeX (whose comments start by `%`) I need to tweak the `g:easy_align_delimiters` variable. Which in my opinion is not right, since it is syntax dependent it should arise in a locale variable with a `filetype` detection.

I cannot use it globally either, since some comments are aligned too far from the corresponding line of code and it takes quite a bit of time to go through each block.

[Tabular](https://github.com/godlygeek/tabular) isn't a solution either, since it aligns everything (including those "general" block comments).

Is there a script or a plugin that, given that syntax recognition is enabled, automatically indents comments in the same fashion as in the sample `.vimrc`?

Comment: Tabular accepts regexes so it actually works for your example: `:Tabularize / ".*`

Answer (score 2):

I'm not familiar with easy align, but by reading the documentation my understanding is that you shouldn't tweak `g:easy_align_delimiters`. As the plugin allows specifying the character along the command or operator, you could define a new command/operator that calls the easy align specifying the correct characters.

Usually the comment characters are set by the ftplugin on the `'commentstring'` option, which is local to the buffer. Thus the new command/operator would need to parse the contents of `&commentstring` and include it dynamically, possible using `:execute`.

Comment: Thanks. Sounds like a good idea and a good way to get familiar with the plugin. Will look at it.